# Multiplying spinner value with array value

Tags: java, android, arrays, spinner

Here is my Code where I want to multiply the value of spinner with array value.

The array gets its value from my other java class named as `Constant` and that class has an array `food calories`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.items_details);
        Spinner mspin=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        Integer[] items = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4};
        ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        mspin.setAdapter(adapter);

        TextView name_select=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.SelectedName);
                name_select.setText(constant.food_items[constant.SelectedIndex]);
        imageView =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagedetail);
        UpdateImage(constant.food_items[constant.SelectedIndex]);

        TextView calories=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.calories111);
                calories.setText(constant.food_calories[constant.index]+"");

        int multiple=0;

        {

             try {multiple= mspin.getSelectedItemPosition()*       constant.food_calories[constant.index];

          TextView tot_calories=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.caloriestotal);
          tot_calories.setText(multiple+"");}

          catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
              Log.e("Error", "Failed to multiply invalid non-numbers");
                   }
```

Constant class code

```
public static final Integer[] food_calories=new Integer[]{74
};
    public static int index = 0;
```

}

Comment: what is your constant class? add this class code.

Comment: @HaniyehKhaksar see this constant class code

Comment: you didn't have any data in your arrays!

Comment: yes public static final Integer[] food_calories=new Integer[]{74
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this problem using this code:

```
//Make these variables global so that it can be accessed in onClickListner.
Integer[] items = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4};
int multiple=0;
ImageView imageView;
TextView tot_calories;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.items_details);
      Spinner mspin=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
      ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
      mspin.setAdapter(adapter);

      TextView name_select=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.SelectedName);
      name_select.setText(constant.food_items[constant.SelectedIndex]);
      imageView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagedetail);
      UpdateImage(constant.food_items[constant.SelectedIndex]);
      TextView calories=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.calories111);
      calories.setText(constant.food_calories[constant.index]+"");

      tot_calories=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.caloriestotal);
      mspin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()     {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { 
      // Your code here
            multiple=items[i]*constant.food_calories[constant.index];
            tot_calories.setText("update Value is: "+multiple);
      } 

      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
      return;
      }

  });
  }
```

Updated my answer! because it is  complete solution now that I have tested myself.

Comment: what do you mean that nothing happened?

Comment: is it updating text in tot_calories textview?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the code that sets the `multiple` variable's value inside a listener for the spinner `mspin` so that it will be called every time the spinner is changed. Add the following code in the `onCreate` method

```
        mspin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Your code to set multiple's value and calculate total calories here...
            try {
                multiple = (int)parent.getItemAtPosition(position) * constant.food_calories[constant.index];
                TextView tot_calories = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.caloriestotal);
                tot_calories.setText(multiple + "");
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                Log.e("Error", "Failed to multiply invalid non-numbers");
            }
        }

        /**
         * Callback method to be invoked when the selection disappears from this view. 
         * The selection can disappear for instance when touch is activated or when the adapter becomes empty.
         * @param arg0
         */
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // You can also do something here, but not necessary
        }
    });
```